# Get Collection (Products) of Objects for each item in a list

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I have `orders` collection that contains `products` collection.I'm passing some product ids as list to the method.I need to return a list of products matching with any of the id in the `input` list.

Do i need to use a foreach loop like this? Please advice ..

```
   public List < ProductOrderData > ListProductsByOrderId(List < Guid > input) {
      List < ProductOrderData > products = new List < ProductOrderData > ();
      foreach(var id in input) {
        var orders = this.Collection.AsQueryable().SelectMany(order => order.Products.Where(product => product.Id == id));
      }

    }
```

Update:
[image]

Update2:
[image]

Update 3:
I pass product Ids and i need to get list of products from orders that match the product Ids.

Comment: whar is `Collection`, please? Some materialized collection like `List<T>`, array `T[]`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Please see update...

Comment: Why a screenshot ? Can't you just copy paste as text ?

Comment: _"Do i need to use a foreach loop like this? Please advice .."_ Let us know if it did work.

Comment: You're saying you pass order IDs to the method but you compare them to product IDs for some reason, there's something wrong here.

Comment: @techno update the question explaining what the actual issue is - you want to query *MongoDb* and load related entities. This has little to do with LINQ itself, it depends on the MongoDB provider you use and its syntax. Most likely it already supports loading nested entities.

Comment: @IvanKashtanov I pass product Ids and i need to get list of products from orders that match the product Id.

Comment: How do you connect to MongoDB, what provider? What is IMongoCollection? Your own interface or a provider interface?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `namespace MongoDB.Driver
{
        public interface IMongoCollection<TDocument>`

Comment: @Cid corrected question...

Comment: @techno update the question. That doesn't say what you use though. Is it MongoDB's own .NET SDK? Or something else?

Comment: LINQ by itself doesn't query databases. The LINQ query is converted into SQL or whatever query language is used by the database. If you simply used local lists, you could put all product IDs into a list or array and write `Where(order=>order.Producs.Any(p=>ids.Contains(p.ID))`. That may or may not translate to MongoDB. If it does, it may or may not be efficient. In a SQL database for example, it would be far easier to filter the products and return their orders

Comment: I don't know how the MongoDb provider is implement for `IQueryable` but in normal Linq this should do the trick: `this.Collection.AsQueryable().SelectMany(order => order.Products).Where(product => ids.Contains(product.Id))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have orders collection that contains products collection.

Okay, so you have something like this:

```
var ordersWithTheirProducts = ...
    .Select(... => new Order
    {
         // some Order properties:
         Id = ...
         OrderDate = ...
         ClientId = ...

         // Products of this Order:
         Products = ...
            .Select( product => new Product
            {
                // Several Product properties
                Id = product.Id,
                Name = product.Name,
                Price = product.Price,
                ...
            },
    };
```

> I'm passing some product ids as list

```
IEnumerable<Guid> productIds = ...
```

> I need to return a list of products matching with any of the id in the input list.

So, you want to select all Products that were used in any of your Orders, and if that Product has an Id that is one of the values in ProductIds, then you want it in your result.

First we extract all Products that are used in your Orders, then we'l remove the Duplicates, and finally we keep only those Products that have an Id in your productIds:

```
var result = Orders.SelectMany(order => order.Products)  // extract all Products
    .Distinct()                                           // remove duplicate products
    .Where(product => productIds.Contains(product.Id))
          // keep only those products with an Id that is in productIds
```

Comment: One more question ... if i need to return a custom class with orderid and product id instead of product as a whole,is it possible to do this in Linq?

Comment: Yes it is. In the Select you see `product => new Product {...}`, replace it with `product => new MyCustomClass {...}`, fill only the properties you want to fetch

Comment: Actually, this is what I'm trying to achieve using LINQ https://www.paste.org/103032

Comment: Well, if the code is what you plan to do use that code. Or does this code not do what you want? Without requirements, I can't tell you what code to use, can I?

Answer (score 1):

iterating over the input guids will cause a query per each guid. instead issue a single command like this:

```cs
    var products = collection.AsQueryable()
                     .Where(o => o.Products.Any(p => input.Contains(p.Id)))
                     .SelectMany(o => o.Products)
                     .Where(p => input.Contains(p.Id))
                     .ToList();
```

first shortlist the orders with the first `where` clause. and then unwind the products with `SelectMany`. because, unwinding the whole collection is a bad idea. unwinding creates objects in server memory and there's a pipeline memory limit of 100mb in mongodb.

test program:

```js
using MongoDB.Entities;
using MongoDB.Entities.Core;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverFlow
{
    public class OrderInfo : Entity
    {
        public Product[] Products { get; set; }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            new DB("test-db");

            var input = new[] { Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid() };

            var orders = new[] {
                new OrderInfo {  Products = new[] { new Product { Id = input[0] } } },
                new OrderInfo {  Products = new[] { new Product { Id = input[1] } } }
            };

            orders.Save();

            var products = DB.Queryable<OrderInfo>() // collection.AsQueryable() for official driver
                             .Where(o => o.Products.Any(p => input.Contains(p.Id)))
                             .SelectMany(o => o.Products)
                             .Where(p => input.Contains(p.Id))
                             .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to loop over your order collection first and then retrieve your products

```
public static List<Product> GetProducts(List<int> ids)
{
    var products = new List<Product>();
    foreach(var order in Orders)
    {
        products.AddRange(order.Products.Where(p => ids.Any(id => id == p.Id)));
    }

    return products;
}
```

Or simply

```
public static List<Product> GetProducts(List<int> ids)
{
    return Orders.
        SelectMany(
        o => o.Products
        .Where(p => ids.Any(id => id == p.Id)))
        .ToList();
}
```